Помощь с решением задачи JS


let rezalt = confirm('Согасны поработать?');

function one(rezalt = true || false) {

  if (rezalt = true) {
    let s = +prompt('Введите число', '');

    let d = +prompt('И ещё одно', '');

    alert(`Ответ будет таким: ${s+d}`)
  } else(alert("Хорошо, поработаем в другой раз"))

}
one();
alert(rezalt);



Суть задачи - делается запрос через confirm на согласие, в случае положительного ответа - запрос двух чисел с последующим их сложением, после чего повторный запрос на работу (возможное повторение). В отрицательном случае - alert("Хорошо, поработаем в другой раз") и конец итерации.
Проблема - не могу добиться вывода "отмены" в случае отрицательного ответа и повторного вывода вопроса в конце итерации в случае положительного ответа. Подскажите пожалуйста где ошибка и по возможности, буду рад подсказкам как решить эту задачу максимально лаконично. Спасибо заранее.

if (rezalt=true){ -> if (rezalt==true){

Такое уже пробовал, проблема осталась. Отмена- не срабатывает. При положительном ответе цикл не повторяется.

Я не вижу в коде цикла.

one(); -> one(rezalt);.

@puffleeck, ваше изменение ничего не меняет, как мне представляется.

@StanislavVolodarskiy пробую создать такую функцию, следующий этап - сделаю разными циклами ту же задачу. Спасибо за участие всё работает.

@puffleeck Спасибо, всё получилось))

@StanislavVolodarskiy, пожалуй... видимо рано еще просыпаться :3

Сомнительный дубликат.

@SwaD, добавил более релевантный дубликат, где-то еще был про = и == но не могу найти пока, возможно закрывали как опечатку такие вопросы

@Golos1901, при такой записи rezalt = true || false - значение rezalt будет всегда true
